# Edge labels at same distances from the center

Tags: tikz-pgf

The attached code draws a vertex with five labelled outgoing edges. The labels should all be placed at the same distance from the center, but at least perceptually they are not. How can I fix this?

```
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=red,draw=black,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{none}=[]
\tikzstyle{edge}=[-,draw=black,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{label}=[pos=0.4, auto, font=\scriptsize]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node [style=vertex] (0) at (0, 0) {};
    \node [style=none] (1) at (-0, 1) {};
    \node [style=none] (2) at (0.95, 0.31) {};
    \node [style=none] (3) at (0.59, -0.81) {};
    \node [style=none] (4) at (-0.59, -0.81) {};
    \node [style=none] (5) at (-0.95, 0.31) {};

    \draw [style=edge] (0) to node[style=label]{1} (1);
    \draw [style=edge] (0) to node[style=label]{2} (2);
    \draw [style=edge] (0) to node[style=label]{3} (3);
    \draw [style=edge] (0) to node[style=label]{4} (4);
    \draw [style=edge] (0) to node[style=label]{5} (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Labels not at (visually) equal distances from center]

Comment: Hint: How did you come up with the node coordinates?

Comment: Good point! This definitely *can* fix the problem, but on the other hand why can't I outsource the math to TikZ? After all, the `pos` *should* exactly do what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem here is to do with `anchor`, which you currently have set to `auto`.

There are a few things we can do to improve things:

- we can use the form `(<angle>,<radius>)` to specify the end points of your radii, and draw the labels using the same `(<angle>,<radius>)` idea
- since we don't need a `node` at the end of each radii, we can simply use a `coordinate`
- we can also use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` as discussed in [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

[image: screenshot]

I have drawn an additional circle just for demonstration here- you can remove it once you're ready for production.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    vertex/.style={circle,fill=red,draw=black,line width=0.8 pt},
    edge/.style={-,draw=black,line width=0.8 pt},
    label/.style={pos=0.4, inner sep=1pt,font=\scriptsize}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
    \node [style=vertex] (0) at (0, 0) {};
    \coordinate  (1) at (90:1);
    \coordinate  (2) at (18:1) ;
    \coordinate  (3) at (-54:1) ;
    \coordinate  (4) at (-126:1) ;
    \coordinate  (5) at (-198:1) ;

    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
    {
        \draw [edge] (0) to (\i);
        \node at ({-360/5*(\i-2)}:.5) {\i};
    }
    \draw  (0,0) circle  (.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As a final comment, there may be reasons *not* to use `label` and `edge` in your own custom styles as these are very meaningful commands already defined in `tikz`- if you do choose to keep them, proceed with caution!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `pins` and use the `\foreach` iterative procedure extensively:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [evaluate={\y=90+\x*360/5;\w=\y+36;\z=int(\x+1);}] \x in {0,...,4}{
    \node [circle,draw,line width=0.8 pt,fill=red,minimum size=1cm,
    pin={[pin edge={line width=0.8 pt,black},pin distance=2cm]\y:$$}] (c) at (0,0) {}; 
    \node at (\w:1.5cm) {\z};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \SpecialCoor
  \psset{linewidth=.5pt,unit=1cm}
  \multido{\iA=90+-72,\iB=1+1}{5}{
    \psline(0,0)(1;\iA)
    \rput(0.5;\number\numexpr\iA-36\relax){\iB}}
  \pscircle[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0,0){0.2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Polar coordinates are specified using `(<r>;<t>)` after setting `\SpecialCoor`. Cartensian coordinates are specified using `(<x>,<y>)` and work by default. [`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido) provides the means to iterate over numeric items.